# Basic mocking scenario with Mockito

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

I started playing with java Mockito framework and with mocking concept. Would you be so kind to explain to me how to test this basic scenario?

There is an usecase A, which has one public method (calculate) and several private/protected methods. Somewhere in the middle of calculate, another usecase is called (B). In order to call B a lot of arguments have to be prepared. B produces also quite complicated output. I would like to prepare test in such a way that I would be able to replace actual call to B with my own stub - quite trivial case. However, A has only one public method calculate and I don't wish to make tests in the same package to get access to protected methods. Redesigning class A could bring more troubles than relief - it is not designed be me, there are some relations between different parts of code that make creating new classes with public methods a bit odd.

Could you tell me some suggestions or point to some readings?

Answer (score 1):

In order to replace the actual B with your own using Mockito (or any other mocking framework) you'll *have* to be able to inject B either manually by creating a constructor

```
public A(B b) { localB = b; }
```

by creating a method

```
public void setB(B b) { localB = b; }
```

or by using some automatic injection framework.

However, If B is completely encapsulated and hidden and that cannot be changed then you can  write tests against B. to show that given known inputs B returns the expected outputs

And then tests against A i.e. given known inputs does A.calculate() give the expected outputs.

If you can show that B behaves as expected and A behaves as expected then you don't need to show that A calls B correctly explicitly since you're testing it implicitly.

---

EDITED because @david wallace has less coffee or more sleep than me!

You don't *have* to inject a **mock** B. If it helps you can inject the actual B but first [create a spy](http://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html) `a.getB();`

```
B spyB = spy(new B());
//maybe stub the method return here    
A a = new A(spyB);
a.calculate();
verify(spyB).complicatedThingForCalculate("a", "lot", "of", "specified", "parameter");
```

Further edit:
As pointed out in the comments you're much better off using a Mock than a spy. From the documentation:

> Real spies should be used carefully and occasionally, for example when
>   dealing with legacy code.

So I included it here as you say you don't want / have the freedom to change A and B.

Comment: The first half of this answer is really good.  But the part about the spy isn't going to work, because the A object will still have a reference to the original B object, not to the spy.  So the verify will fail, even if the method on B is actually called.

Comment: The actual reason I want to get rid of calling B from A is: I need to provide much more arguments to calculate (A). If I would be able to stub call to B, it would be convenient. Isn't mocking and stubbing just about that? It would be easy if I had more public methods but I am not allowed to change interface. Thanks for the responses so far.

Comment: Yep, but to stub the call to B you have to be able to isolate it. So either you create a Mock A and you tell it that when you call calculate with a particular set of parameters it should give you a set return or you Mock B and do the same. If you can't get to the B because it's hidden inside calculate then you can't mock it

Comment: Commenting on your edited version - you should still use a mock of B, not a spy; because using a mock would remove the dependency of your test for A on your code for B.  One of the nice things about using a mocking framework is that your tests become very robust; your test for A can't break when you change the code for B.  But using a spy the way you have will break that notion by introducing a dependency where there should be none.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your class A creates an instance of class B.  That always causes problems for testability, because it's hard to make it create a mock instance instead.  One really good way to handle this is to allow for the injection of a factory class for class B.  This is "pattern 2" in [my wiki post on this topic](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation)

Comment: Or just use [PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class)](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13).